# User .fonts.conf file not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: 18.04, fonts, configuration, python3

Here's my Ubuntu `.fonts.conf` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM “fonts.dtd”>
<fontconfig>
        <match target=”font”>
                <edit name=”autohint” mode=”assign”>
                        <bool>true</bool>
                </edit>
        </match>
</fontconfig>
```

When I launch a particular Python file I get the following error:

> $ python3 proj_plot.py
>
> Fontconfig error: "/home/int/.fonts.conf", line 2: not well-formed (invalid token)
>
> Fontconfig error: "/home/int/.fonts.conf", line 2: not well-formed (invalid token)

I'm not sure what this means and how to correct this. Would appreciate some help.

> $ uname -r
>
> 5.0.0-32-generic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use typographic double quotes `“` instead of straight quotation marks `"`. (You probably copied and pasted an example from a web page that favoured style over syntax.)

Change each `“` to `"` and try again.

I didn't notice the wrong quotes until I pasted your conf file into https://jsonformatter.org/xml-parser. If you try it, you'll see yellow warning triangles appear next to the quotes.